# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi' - While deploying in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am deploying a small Flask application in Heroku and facing this error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

My Requirement.txt using pip:

```
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
playsound==1.2.2
requests==2.21.0
ruamel.yaml==0.15.92
urllib3==1.24.2
vext==0.7.3
vext.gi==0.7.0
Werkzeug==0.15.2
pgi==0.0.10.1
```

My Actual code:

```
from flask import render_template
import requests
from playsound import playsound
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    counter = 1
    user = {'username': 'Mr Test'}
    playsound('audio.mp3')
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)
```

error message:

```
2019-04-19T17:52:05.415693+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/playsound.py", line 91, in _playsoundNix
2019-04-19T17:52:05.415694+00:00 app[web.1]: import gi
2019-04-19T17:52:05.415695+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Comment: Are you using `pip` (with `requirements.txt`) or Pipenv (with `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`)? Please [edit] your question and add whichever of those dependencies files you're using.

Comment: Hey Chris, yes I am using pip with requirement.txt? Do you want me to post my requirement.txt here?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and paste it in there. Format it as code using the `{}` button or Ctrl+K.

Comment: done. Apologies for if any inconvenience, pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three issues here:

1. You're depending on [`vext`](https://github.com/stuaxo/vext), a library to

   > Use system python packages in virtualenv.

   It's very likely that whatever system packages you're trying to use aren't available on Heroku. You may be able to install them as Ubuntu packages using [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) including the [`apt` buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) and an `Aptfile`, but it probably makes more sense to just install them in your virtualenv.

   `vext` claims that some packages don't work well that way, but getting them to work in a virtualenv is probably a better thing to ask about.
2. [`vext.gi`](https://pypi.org/project/vext.gi/) specifically is designed to

   > Allow use of system gi.repository (Gtk3) from a virtualenv

   GTK3 is a graphical toolkit that doesn't make much sense to run on a web host. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with it, but you'll probably have to rethink that approach.
3. You're also using [`playsound`](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/), a

   > Pure Python, cross platform, single function module with no dependencies for playing sounds

   This doesn't make much sense on Heroku, either. `playsound` might seem to work on your local machine, but that's just because your server is running on the same machine as your browser. `playsound` probably won't work at all on Heroku, but if it does it will play a sound on some server in an Amazon datacenter. You won't be able to hear it.

   Like with GTK3, you're going to have to rethink this part of your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your time and inputs. Vext I used, as it was suggested in multiple places to fix 'gi' not found issue. That I will remove.

For playsound I totally agree it doesn't make sense, my main intention is to play a sound in a browser when a post / get request is submitted. Can you be kind enough to throw some ideas ?

Comment: @ArjitSharma, do you know the root cause of the "`gi` not found" issue? Are you using this module yourself elsewhere in your code, or does one of your libraries depend on it? Again, if it's for GTK3 I suspect a larger architectural issue that needs to be resolved. Playing a sound in the browser will have to be done with JavaScript. Please search for a tutorial and try what you find.

Comment: yes - it was due to playsound - they use gi. 
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/playsound.py"."line 91"
-----------------------------

I know, I have to use Javascript and Websocket in Flask - just was trying to avoid, if I can get a easy solution. Anyway thanks a ton :-)